# Add more css classes in one function

Tags: onchange, onblur, onmousedown

I need to create a function with this: 
onMouseDown to add that class,onChange that other class and onBlur last class.
With ".animate" is more wonderful, but is ok even without.

```
onMouseDown="this.className='styleDropDownClick';
onChange="this.className='styleDropDown'";
onBlur="this.className='styleDropDown';
```

If anyoane can help me , thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following functions:

```
    function styleDropDownClick() {

        var textForm = document.forms["textForm"];
        textForm.fname.setAttribute("class", "styleDropDownClick");
    }
    function styleDropDown() {
        var textForm = document.forms["textForm"];
        textForm.fname.setAttribute("class", "styleDropDown");
    }
```

This works with the following HTML:

```
   <form id="textForm">
       <input type="text" class="styleDropDown" name="fname"
           onBlur="styleDropDown()" onChange="styleDropDown()" onMouseDown="styleDropDownClick()" value="test"/>
       <input type="text" class="styleDropDown" name="fname2" value="test2"/>
   </form>
```

Comment: not really work, see the example: http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/130/. The select is not expanding on all value width for IE8 :(

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work? In the example I've given, I tested with an <input type="text" onBlur="styleDropDown" ...>. The <input> has name (not id) fname and is wrapped in a form with name <textForm>. In fact, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: In your example, you've copied the code above verbatim even though you have no form called textForm. Also, the class in your select is "styleDDC", not "styleDropDownClick" as in your CSS. Copy the above functions and HTML into a text file (with <html> and your own CSS, etc). Also, make your CSS very distinguishable so the change is obvious (change colour or something). Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also use document.getElementById to get your input field, rather than obtaining the form through document.getForms[] and accessing the <input> by fname.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a craftsman in the jquery code, I'm more designer ... so I try to learn how to use document.getElementById. I know how to use that in html but I have more controls and I don't want to modify in each html page for that, a script will be more helpful. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Ok, though all this is just javascript, not jquery. The key thing I was showing above is that, once you have your element (say an <input type="text">), you set the class attribute using `setAttribute("class", "styleDropDown")`. It doesn't matter how you get the element. In your example on jsfiddle.net you have a few other errors that prevent this working: (1) You haven't registered for any events on your <select>, (2) you've set its initial class to be a class that you've not declared in your CSS (as I said above), (3) you used my example verbatim, rather than pick key parts out for your demo.

Comment: Thank you for your support wmorrison365 :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! My problew was that the child of select is not expanding with auto width or a given width.

```
 $("select").click(function () {
    $(this).children().addClass("cooling");
    });
```

here is an example, it works only for IE

http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/132/